# Let  be a relation on a non-empty set . Define, explicitly in terms of , the relation which is the symmetric closure of .

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let  be a relation on a non-empty set . Define, explicitly in terms of , the relation which is the symmetric closure of . You should prove that your relation is indeed the smallest symmetric relation on  containing  as a subset.

***What I've tried***

Let $R$ be a relation on a non-empty set $A$

Thus $x,y \in A | xRy$

Let $S$ be a symmetric closure of $R$.

$ S = R \cup R^{-1}$

$S$ = {$(x,y) \in A$x$A| x R y$} $\cup$ {$(y,x)\in A$x$A|xRy$}

Thus $S$ is symmetric by inspection.

1- Suppose $S'$ is a smaller symmetrical closure

2- $\exists a,b \in S|$it is not part of S' and are symmetric.

3- However from above we have shown that S contains all symmetrical pairs of elements (as it is a symmetric closure).

by 2 and 3, we have reached a contradiction.

Thus S is the smallest symmetric relation on A containing R as a subset.

Answer (score 0):

Is the symmetric closure of R defined as the smallest symmetric relation containing R?

You neglected to give an explicit formula for symmetric closure.
All you did was to show that the smallest is unique.

Exercise.  Prove S = R $\cup$ R$^{-1}$ is symmetric.
In addition, prove that if K is a symmetric relation for the same set of elements, that K is a subset of S.

Comment: let $S = R \cup R^{-1}$ 
Choose $(x,y) \in R \cup R^{-1}$
To show that S is symmetrical, it suffice to show that $(y,x) \in R \cup R^{-1}$.
Since we know that $(x,y)$ is either $\in R$ or $\in R^{-1}$ 

I dont really know how to progress from here...

Comment: Do both cases xRy and xR$^{-1}$y.

Comment: $R$ = {(x,y) $\in A$ | x R y}
$R^{-1}$ = {(y,x) $\in A$ | x R y} 
Since $S = R \cup R^{-1}$, as defined above (y,x) is part of S.

Comment: A is undefined.  Do the first part, xRy..

Comment: i've edited my response! please take a look!

Comment: @CXY.  Terrible.  See edit.